# Proving certain inequality related to Primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was reading the following paper. But I can't understand why the last line concerning $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is true. The proof is a work of Sylvester.
I would be happy if someone helps me in understanding why the last inequality follows.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Well, we have $M>\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac 1{p_i^2}\right)=\frac 1{\zeta(2)}=\frac 6{\pi^2}$.  I don't see how to improve that lower bound to $\frac 2{\pi}$.  (the two bounds are quite close but $\frac 2{\pi}$ is a bit greater).

Comment: @lulu Haven't you just shown that the claim is false for sufficiently large $N$?

Comment: @saulspatz  Perhaps I'm not clear what the claim is. I thought we were bounding $M$, but now I am unsure.  I agree that my argument shows that $\frac 2{\pi}>M>\frac 6{\pi^2}$ for large $N$.

Comment: @lulu The only thing that makes sense in my opinion (but is a wee bit wrong for sufficiently large $N$) is that Sylvester claims $M > \frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: How are you showing $\frac{2}{\pi} > M?$ @lulu

Comment: @DanielFischer  Well, that's what I thought, but unless I have botched the calculation (always possible) I think $M$ tends to $\frac 6{\pi^2}$ which is (slightly) lower.

Comment: @mathisfun  my argument is:  As $N\to \infty$ we have $M\to \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac 1{p_i^2}\right)=\frac 1 {\zeta(2)}=\frac 6{\pi^2}$ which is slightly less than $\frac 2{\pi}$.

Comment: I was under the impression that Sylvester was claiming that $M \log{N} > \frac2\pi$

Comment: Now that I re-read it, I see what you mean.  I thought it $M>\frac2\pi$, but perhaps it means $M\log N>\frac2\pi$.  However, that's false when $N=2$, so I guess  not.  It might be helpful to see the next few paragraphs of the paper.

Comment: @lulu Yes, for large $N$, $M$ is very close to $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. Hence the claim is wrong for large $N$. However, since $$\prod_{p \leqslant N} \frac{p}{p-1} \sim e^{\gamma}\log N\,,$$ we indeed have $$\prod_{p \leqslant N} \frac{p+1}{p} > \frac{2}{\pi}\log N\,.$$ But that is a bit harder to prove.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Right.  But, as you say, I don't think that sharper bound follows from anything in the given text.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it was [re-posted and answered on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362084/proving-certain-inequality-related-to-primes).